# Eine Alternative zu "meistens"

Tags: word-usage

Ich suche nach einer Alternative zum Adverb *meistens* in diesem Zusammenhang:

> Wir haben *meistens* auf Deutsch gesprochen, da ich mein Sprechen verbessern wollte.

Ich frage mich, ob ich in diesem Kontext entweder *größtenteils* oder *hauptsächlich* benutzen kann. Verändert es sich die Bedeutung des Satzes dadurch?

Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: I'm not sure what that sentence meant to say, but I believe you want to know whether the meaning of the sentence would change. If that's not what you meant, you should edit.

Comment: Mehr Kontext ist notwendig: "In meiner Kindheit haben wir meistens Deutsch gesprochen" ist OK, aber im Sinne von "Wir haben gestern die meiste Zeit Deutsch geredet" finde ich "meistens" keine gute Wahl. So oder so, "hauptsächlich" und "größtenteils" sind gute Alternative für beide Fälle. (siehe auch Emanuel's Antwort, die sich genau auf diesen Aspekt bezieht.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt einen kleinen Unterschied zwischen "meistens" und den beiden anderen Wörtern. Die Frage ist:

- Sprichst du über ein Gespräch oder mehrere?

"Meistens" bezieht sich IMMER auf mehrere Gespräche.

> Wir haben heute beim Meeting meistens Deutsch gesprochen.

Das funktioniert, das der Kontext hier keine andere Deutung zulässt, aber es klingt ein bisschen(sehr) komisch.
"Hauptsächlich" ist sehr offen. Es kann eure Kommunikation insgesamt oder ein einzelnes Gespräch beschreiben.
"Größtenteils" klingt, zumindest für mich, sehr nach einer Gesprächssituation, kann aber auch generell gemeint sein.
Weitere Alternativen sind:

> die meiste Zeit (1 Gespräch)
>   den Großteil der Zeit (1 Gespräch)
>   überwiegend (generell)

Comment: "meist" (generell) würde auch schon reichen.

Answer (score 0):

"Auf Deutsch" passt hier nicht, "Deutsch" oder "deutsch" (beides geht, siehe § 58 E2 der Regeln des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung, 2006) reicht aus:

> Wir haben meistens deutsch/Deutsch gesprochen, da ich mein Deutsch verbessern
>   wollte.

"Hauptsächlich" kann ebenfalls verwendet werden, ohne dass sich die Aussage verändert. "Größtenteils" geht, es könnte sich aber auch darauf beziehen, dass der größere Teil einer Gruppe Deutsch, der kleinere Englisch gesprochen hat. Diese Tatsache würde man allerdings eher durch "mehrheitlich" ausdrücken.

"Am öftesten" würde ich auf keinen Fall verwenden, 1. weil man Adverbien nicht steigert (wenn schon, dann "am häufigsten") und 2. weil der Superlativ nur sinnvoll ist, wenn mindestens drei Sprachen gesprochen wurden. Der Komparativ ist aber zu schwach, um "meistens" zu ersetzen.

Comment: Warum kann man nicht "auf Deutsch" sagen? Was müsste man tun, damit "auf Deutsch" korrekt/akzeptabel wäre?

Comment: Wenn man hervorheben will, dass in einer bestimmten Situation Deutsch verwendet wird statt z.B. Englisch, könnte man sagen: "Wir unterhalten uns heute auf Deutsch" oder "Wir führen heute das Gespräch auf Deutsch". Also in diesem Fall "Wir haben uns meist auf Deutsch unterhalten". In diesen Wendungen sollte man "auf" nicht weglassen. Ansonsten meist in der Formulierung "xy heißt auf Deutsch yz", oder als Redewendung "auf gut Deutsch". Das bezieht sich also auf die Übersetzung einzelner Begriffe oder Wendungen.

Comment: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/deutsch-sprechen_auf-deutsch.php

Comment: Ich schätze Daniel Scholten als Sprachkritiker und Spezialisten sehr, folge ihm aber nicht überall hin.

Comment: Fair enough. Da ich aber durchaus im Sprachgebrauch "auf Deutsch" im gegebenen Kontext verwende und für mich es mit und ohne "auf" vollkommen OK ist, folge ich hier der Gegenpartei ;)